# Sqldatareader and rowcount

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a query:

```
declare @Code nvarchar(100)
select @Code="BMW"
select name from NewCars where code=@Code
if @@rowcount = 0
Select name from OldCars where code=@Code
```

In Sql managment studio first part give me 0 resuklts, and second 1 one result, and that is ok, but
in sqldatareader I use the same query ofcource without:

```
declare @Code nvarchar(100)
select @Code="BMW"
```

because I use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", "BMW");
```

And

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                Name= reader["Name"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new NotSupportedException("Lack of car with this Code");
                        }
                    }
```

gives me zero result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database results multiple results, so if the first result is empty you would need to use `reader.NextResult()` to move on to the second result.

You can also make the query return a single results by checking if the first select would contain anything:

```
declare @Code nvarchar(100)
select @Code="BMW"
if (exists(select * from NewCars where code=@Code)) begin
  select name from NewCars where code=@Code
end else begin
  select name from OldCars where code=@Code
end
```